# What is the best way to setup an AWS RDS Dev Team Environment (using MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using a LAMP Stack hosting everything in AWS.

For my production servers, I have the DB Server sitting behind the webserver, and not accessible to the internet.

For my development instance, I have it setup similarly, in the same VPC, with a public/private subnet, and a route enabled via IP addresses to access it from outside AWS.  This way, I can connect SQL Developer on my local computer and code/develop on my local computer while having access to my dev database.

However, I am now in the process of hiring several interns, and I don't think adding their individual IP addresses to allow them connectivity is the best approach.  Especially since some of them may be coming from college campuses and IP addresses are not static.

After some searching around, I can't seem to find the best approach to setup AWS to enable a dev environment and a group of folks access to the DB from their local machines.

Should I setup a VPN?
Should I continue to use the IP address method?

Am I missing something?

I can't imagine I'm the only one in this boat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would set up a VPN.

Comment: Yeah, it crossed my mind.  Seemed more complicated and expensive than needed but may be the best approach.